# Variant Api android in Gradle 4.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In previous version of gradle I have such code as below for generating outputFileName for my release apk.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(outputPathName)
        }
    }
```

But after last gradle update this code is not working. I have read on official migrating docs that I should change my code to:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

And this is not working. This code just creates path in `/home/pugman/AndroidStudioProjects/clickerapp/app/build/outputs/apk/release` directory.
Also I have read this text:

"However, more complicated tasks that involve accessing outputFile objects no longer work. That's because variant-specific tasks are no longer created during the configuration stage. This results in the plugin not knowing all of its outputs up front, but it also means faster configuration times."

Does this means that method above will not work?

Comment: post your full `build.gradle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the [official migration docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output) states that there have been breaking changes introduced in 3.0.0. With that said, it also says clearly:

> It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK name during
>   build time

And indeed it does :)
But I suspect that you're probably doing something wrong in your `build.gradle`. Anyways, notice that they prefix `applicationVariants` with `android` in the example:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

But, the prefix is not needed **unless** you're outside the `android` closure, e.g.:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    // More stuff here...
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

If this doesn't solve the issue then most likely you issue is somewhere else in your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

in your module **build.gradle.kts**

```
androidComponents.onVariants { variant ->
    variant.outputs.forEach { output ->
        if (output is com.android.build.api.variant.impl.VariantOutputImpl) {
            output.outputFileName.set("your file name")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.